# Correcting topology error in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, topology, network

I am interested in tools to correct `topology` errors in `PostGIS`, focussing on road networks. Is there a tool that corrects `topology` errors automatically, so that I can use the network for routing?

I am aware that there is something like `osm2pgrouting`. But I am trying to analyse the network in `ArcGIS`. Hence, I want to repair the `topology` in `PostGIS` and then import the network into `ArcGIS`.

Comment: I don't know about correcting errors, but for finding them, see [ValidateTopology](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ValidateTopology.html). Postgis topo isn't trivial to use, are there not tools for this in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS topology functions are different to pgRouting's network topology. pgRouting's topology is very simple and it allows for example intersecting linestrings, which would cause an error with PostGIS topology validation.
In fact pgRouting only needs valid `source` and `target` ID's to describe the network.

That said, a typical problem might be disconnected linestrings, but `pgr_createtopology` has a "snapping tolerance" parameter, that treats two lines as connected automatically, if their start and/or end points are very close.
http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_createTopology.html#pgr-create-topology

And there are a few other "Topology Functions", that may be helpful to identify errors, see: http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/topology-functions.html#topology-functions

These functions do not fix problems automatically, but you eventually can use their results to do so.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Was searching for an overview of all the functions!